# Do learners require the task to be split in to train and test sets, or do they do it themselves

Tags: r, mlr3

The code below is the sample from the [mlr3cluster Github repo](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3cluster). My question is whether the learner is overtrained, due to the task not being split into a train and test set, or does it take care of that on its own internally?

My guess is that it does but I'm just not sure and I'm new to R and mlr3 and can't seem to find documentation regarding this topic.

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3cluster)

task = mlr_tasks$get("usarrests")
learner = mlr_learners$get("clust.kmeans")
learner$train(task)
preds = learner$predict(task = task)
```

Comment: Typically, the data set needs to be split by the modeller (you), as you may want to choose which part of the data to use for training/modelling, and what part for testing/validation. Check out https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/train.html , i.e. scroll down to `further options/comments`: By default, the whole data set in the Task() is used for training. The subset argument of train() takes a logical or integer vector that indicates which observations to use, for example if you want to split your data into a training and a test set ...

Comment: @Ray Thanks for helping. Mlr is deprecated since 2 years and given that this is an mlr3 question, it would be great to link to the respective mlr3 resource, which is https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, learners don't split the data for themselves. The [resampling part of the mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/perf-eval-cmp.html#resampling) has much more detail on this -- the short version is that mlr3 provides many ways of splitting your data automatically that you can then use to evaluate the models learners induce in an unbiased fashion.

All of that said, for clustering this doesn't really apply in the same way. This is because clustering is an unsupervised method (i.e. there's no ground truth data we want the model to learn). So what you're doing in your code is fine if all you're interested in is how observations are assigned to clusters for further analysis.

However, if you are treating this as a classification problem (i.e. you want the clustering to recover the classes that are contained in the original task), you do need to split into training and testing. In that case I would recommend using a classification learner instead of a clustering method though.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up. Since I'm way more used to classification problems and using classifiers I confused the two, as I'm using the Iris dataset which allows me to (I guess) "validate" the cluster analysis.